# ¿Is it possible to use a table alias generated in a lateral subquery in another lateral subquery?

Tags: postgresql, lateral-join

The doubt arises from a scenario like this:

- I have a table named `one_table` that has many related rows in another table named `another_table`, via foreign key like this `another_table(one_table_id) references table(id)`
- 1️⃣ I want to discard the rows of `another_table` that has null in `column_a` and do relate to the a row in `one_table`
- 2️⃣ over the rows not discarted in the first step I want to have rows that fulfills a given condition (`column_b = 'a'`)
- 3️⃣ over the rows not discarted in the first step I want to have rows that fulfills another given condition (`column_b = 'b'`)

So I write a query like this:

```
select *
from one_table t
cross join lateral (
    select *
    from another_table at
    where t.id = at.one_table_id and at.column_a is null
) as filtered_corelated_table -- 1️⃣
cross join lateral (
    select *
    from filtered_corelated_table fct
    where fct.column_b = 'a'
) as filtered_1 -- 2️⃣
cross join lateral (
    select *
    from filtered_corelated_table fct
    where fct.column_b = 'b'
) as filtered_2 -- 3️⃣
```

And i'm getting an error that says that relation "filtered_corelated_table" doesn't exists.

TD;DR:

Clearly the symbol `filtered_corelated_table` is not reachable within other laterals subqueries... but I do wonder if there is a way to archieve it and if it is not possible AND IF it is not possible to do it, then I would like to ask... ¿ why is not possible? I thought that table alias defined in lateral subqueries are available in other joins... i guess I was wrong...

I solved problem using another query.

As always, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you have to use nested subqueries for that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks.... if you know where is that written in the documentation I would like to know... I have read [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) and nothing is stated regarding combining lateral queries

Comment: I think that you are mixing things up. You want the `WITH` clause, not lateral joins.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe indeed I believe I could solved it using a CTE.. I just stomp into this scenario and wonder about the "power" of laterals subqueries... and.. at the end of the day... wondering about my memory and knowledge about postgres and laterals joins!